# Thin lens is actually prism?

Tags: optics, lenses

I just found in one book that thin lens is nothing but combination of small angled prisms. How is it even possible ? Can someone provide me satisfactory explanation for it?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a diagram to show how you might think of a lens as a collection of prisms.

[image]

There is also a [Fresnel lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens) is made from a series of prisms as shown below.

[image]

Which looks like this in real life.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This supplements the images given in the answer by @Farcher.

Underlying the images is the Fermat Principle of Least Time.

This passage from Feynman's *QED: The Strange Story of Light and Matter* (pp. 57-58) describes the process using his approach to quantum mechanics.
(bolding mine)

> Now, let's have some fun. Let's "fool the light," so that
> all the paths take exactly the same amount of time. How
> can we do this? How can we make the shortest path,
> through M, take exactly the same time as the longest path,
> through A?
> Well, light goes slower in water than it does in air; it also
> goes slower in glass (which is much easier to handle!). So,
> if we **put in just the right thickness of glass on the shortest
> path, through M, we can make the time for that path exactly
> the same as for the path through A.** The paths next to M,
> which are just a little longer, won't need quite as much glass
> (see Fig. 36). The nearer we get to A, the less glass we have
> to put in to slow up the light. By carefully calculating and
> putting in just the right thickness of glass to compensate
> for the time along each path, we can make all the times the
> same. When we draw the arrows for each way the light
> could go, we find we have succeeded in straightening them
> all out--and there are, in reality, millions of tiny arrows--so
> the net result is a sensationally large, unexpectedly enormous final arrow! Of course you know what I'm describing;
> it's a **focusing lens**. By arranging things so that all the times
> are equal, we can focus light--we can make the probability
> very high that light will arrive at a particular point, and
> very low that it will arrive anywhere else.
>
> [image: Feynman-p57-58-Fig36]
>
> FIGURE 36. A "trick" can be played on Nature by slowing down the light
> that takes shorter paths: glass of just the right thickness is
> inserted so that all the paths will take exactly the same time.
> This causes all of the arrows to point in the same direction,
> and to produce a whopping final arrow--lots of light!
> Such a piece of glass made to greatly increase the probability of light getting
> from a source to a single point is called a focusing lens.

Comment: This reasoning applies individually to the segments of a Fresnel lens, but not to the whole thing.

Comment: I concur with John Doty. In the case of a focusing Fresnel lens the light has multiple paths available from a single point of emission to a single point of reception, and those paths have different duration. This means that the notion of "least time" is *not* applicable in the case of a Fresnel lens. The criterion of "least time" is applicable if and only if: (1) There is only a single available path or: (2) the setup is arranged such that while allowing multiple paths all paths have the same duration